# Estimating parameters for a set of related random variables

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, hierarchical-bayesian, approximate-bayesian-computation, map-estimation

Suppose I have some random variables

$$X_i \sim Dist(\theta_i)$$

for $i = 1, ..., n$ where $Dist$ is some known probability distribution family and $\theta_i$ are some parameters which may vary depending on $i$. But I know that they only vary relatively little, which is a property I want to exploit in the following problem.

Now I have some samples from the each of the random variable, say $x_{1,1}, ..., x_{1,k_1}, x_{2,1}, ...., x_{2,k_2}, ..., x_{n,1}, ..., x_{n,k_n}$. Where $k_i$ is obviously the number of samples drawn from $X_i$. Now some $k_i$ are large enough to give a reliable $\theta_i$ estimate, but some are very little and I am at risk at getting nonsense values if I try to estimate $\theta_i$. However, knowing that the other random variables are likely to have similar values, I think I could perhpas go to some Bayesian probability for help. I want to use the information from the rest of the dataset to construct some apriori distribution $\theta_i \sim Prior(\Theta)$ and update it with the evidence $x_{i,1},...,x_{i,k_i}$ regardless of whether $k_i$ is big or small and estimate the $\theta_i$ as maximum maximum aposteriori probability. (I.e. the idea is to force $\theta_i$ to have some "typical" value for small $k_i$ and to converge to MLE as $k_i \to \infty$.) To make things worse $X_i$ and $X_j$ may not be independent, although we can perhaps assume independence for the sake of developing the idea if that helps anything.

The problem is: How do I get a good estimate for the hyperparamers $\Theta$ from the dataset? Especially if the $Prior$ distribution does not have the conjugate property? Is it perhaps a good idea to try to introduce a hyperprior to express the idea that the $\theta_i$ s are similar? Could you point me to some resources? Is even actually computationally doable even for some very simple cases like $Dist(\theta_i) = Poisson(\lambda_i)$?